# Extracting first value of pair type in python

Tags: python

If i am getting data in the following format:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 8)]
```

I understand that this is basically a list of pair tuples, I basically was thinking what is the most effective way of getting the first value of each tuple. So for the above case I would want to get value `[1,3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
list = [ x[0] for x in values ]
```

Where values is your list of elements

Answer (score 0):

Python's list comprehension should do the trick and tuples can be accessed using indices just like lists.

```
>>> l = [(1, 2), (3, 8)]
>>> [x[0] for x in l]
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, to get [1,3] from [(1, 2), (3, 8)]:

```
>>> a = [(1, 2), (3, 8)]
>>> print [a[0][0], a[1][0]]
[1, 3]
```

From that, the pattern will be:

```
>>> [b[0] for b in a]
[1, 3]
```